# Xamarin: Mock Location App crashes but its NOT a permission prob

Tags: xamarin, gps

for my new app (and first...) im trying to build a location faker. So ive got my own coordinates and i want to fill them into my mocking method. I install the app on my phone and then, ofc, set it under debug info as "mock location app". Now when I click the button to set the new location as mock location the app simply crashes. It must be this part of the code, anyone here made any experiences with mock locations in c#? thanks!

```
    public static void SetMockLocation()
    {
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        var locationManager = context.GetSystemService(LocationService) as LocationManager;

        locationManager.AddTestProvider("Test", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Power.Low, Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);
        locationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled("Test", true);

        var location = new Location("Test");
        location.Latitude = Activity1.Add700ToCoordinates();
        location.Longitude = Activity1.GlobalLongitude;
        locationManager.SetTestProviderLocation("Test", location);

}
```

NEWS:
I was smart: i started the app from my pc, than clicked it down, added it as "allow mock location" and then hit the button. Now I get this:

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incomplete location object, missing timestamp or accuracy? Location[Test5 53,614610,10,032280 acc=??? et=?!?]

Can anybody help?

thanks!

Comment: which line causes the crash?

Comment: thats a good question . unfortunately, i cannot answer that. The reason is that i can not debug the app i have to install it to my phone and then launch is. That is because i need to always set it as "allow mock location" under dev. options which is impossible when i launch the app from my pc...